# Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-firebaseui' in

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebaseui

I have installed react-firebaseui multiple times and it is inside my package.lock.json but I still get an issue when running npm start which says module not found... I am completely lost.

Answer (score 0):

Try this steps:

1. remove node_modules
2. remove package.lock.json
3. yarn install
4. npm start

Comment: I am facing the same issue, can you please explain why this error occurs and how do these steps solve it?